# adb shell keyeven 279 check_output returns none

Tags: python, android, adb, keyevent

I've made a similar question, but was explained bad. I deleted it and I'm making this one.
Basically my task is to press a button on an android emulator, this button will copy a text, I need this text on python script. So what I'm doing is:

```
super().tap(978, 537) #tap function to tap a screen
super().tap(193, 686) #tap function to tap the mentioned button
ret = subprocess.run(f'{adb_path} -s 127.0.0.1:5556 shell input keyevent 279', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(ret.decode('uft-8')
```

the thing is: the text is copied, because if I do the above command it will paste on the android emulator the copied text. But this is not going to return on python script the value of this command. I mean, it will return an empty string even if the text is copied.

That's the output:

```
CompletedProcess(args='"{ADB_PATH}" -s 127.0.0.1:5556 shell input keyevent 279', returncode=0, stdout=b'', stderr=b'')
```

Do you guys know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I may understood that keyevent 279 doesnt return anything. So that may be why this lines doesnt works. But what's the adb shell command to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you can modify your app so that when text is copied, you can write a message to logcat and read it from there with python.

Comment: Ok well, I was now going into this direction, and now the copied text is in logcat under the tag I HCALL   : hcallSetClipboardTextRpc. Do you have any idea how to get it from there?

Comment: `adb logcat`: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat